# React-tooltip displays twice when using MUI icon

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-tooltip

Whenever I add a tooltip to an SVG (using react-toolip), the tooltip shows twice:
[image: Here you can see the overlapped double tooltip]

The Code:

```
<HelpIcon data-tip='This field represents all sales (or revenues) generated by the company.'></HelpIcon>
<ReactTooltip effect='solid' place='left' multiline={true}/>
```

While using the HelpIcon from @mui:

```
import HelpIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Help';
import ReactTooltip from 'react-tooltip';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Material UI tooltip also Its easy to manage and also long text can be used easily

```
import { Tooltip } from '@mui/material';

<Tooltip title='your tooltip title' >
   <HelpIcon>
</Tooltip>
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, define the data-for attribute and the id for the regarding tooltip:

```
<div data-tip='This field represents all sales (or revenues) generated by the company.' data-for='questionMarkToolTip'>
    <HelpIcon></HelpIcon>
    <ReactTooltip effect='solid' place='left' multiline={true} id='questionMarkToolTip'/>
</div>
```